# Where can I ask for algorithm recommendations?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I recently asked this [question on Stack Overflow, now moved to Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/54652/what-s-the-best-algorithm-for-arabic-transliteration).

Where can I ask about algorithm recommendations? Because there are two algorithms for what I'm trying to do, and both have a very high error rate, at least for my case. It seems that Stack Overflow is not the right place for algorithm recommendations.

Comment: Related [meta question on cs.SE](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1560/are-questions-about-algorithm-recommendation-accepted-here).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour) would be the best choice. Asking for an algorithm recommendation would be on-topic, as long as you do everything [here](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) when asking your question. There's an [algorithms](/questions/tagged/algorithms) tag that would be perfect for your question.

Comment: Can I ask it on Programmers.se? Or CS.SE? My problem with Softrec is that it's not that active nowadays, plus many of it's visitors are not programmers, because it's for everyone. A CS studying natural language processing or any programmer, might be more able to answer it.

Comment: @Lynob you probably *could* ask on cs.se, but I would bet it would be much more well-received on SR.SE

Comment: @Lynob asking for recommendations is off topic on [softwareengineering.se]

Comment: It would also be out of scope at CS.SE;  Software Recommendation SE fills the void for that purpose